# How to fix gem file in rails app after changing gem versions? (github, heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

First, I am an idiot, and I know this question may be a bit vague.  I have a rails site that I pushed to github, and I was then trying to push it to heroku and I changed a few of the gems.  I do have gems mentioned twice in gem file, the second under group :development do, but it was running locally.  I got to where I was getting a message about "trying to install in deployment mode after changing gem file".

I then just decided to delete the github repository and try to start over.  Now it seems that it is linked to the old repository and it will not let me create a new repository. here is some command line of what i get when i try,

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:~ cccmusicality$ cd aw2b
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:aw2b cccmusicality$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in            /Users/cccmusicality/aw2b/.git/
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:aw2b cccmusicality$ git add .
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:aw2b cccmusicality$ git commit -m "try"
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:aw2b cccmusicality$ git remote add origin       https://github.com/cccmusicality/aw2b.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:aw2b cccmusicality$ git push -u origin     master
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/cccmusicality/basic.git/' not    found
```

So,

How do I unlink the git init from the old github repo?

I just want to start over and try again.  I also assume my gem file might be a bit unoerfect, here it is,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
"https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

 gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'

 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
 gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
 # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
 gem 'sqlite3'
 # Use Puma as the app server
 gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
 # Use SCSS for stylesheets
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
 # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported   runtimes
 # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

 # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
 gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
 # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
 gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
 # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
 # gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
 # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
 # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

 # Use Capistrano for deployment
 # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

 group :development, :test do
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
 gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
 end

 group :development do
   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
   gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
   gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
   # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
   gem 'spring'
   gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
   gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
 end

 # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
 gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Thank you any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually deleting your .git file from your repo?

`rm -rf .git`

Or you can do in the GUI in your local repo. You may have to go on github and manually delete the repo as well.

Comment: Thank you guys so much I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Update origin url:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/cccmusicality/aw2b.git
```